# Gradients not being visualized in tf.keras Tensorboard (TF2-beta)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I've got the code

```
    # Tensorboard callback
    tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir,
                                                 histogram_freq=1,
                                                 write_grads=True,
                                                 write_images=True)
```

which is supposed to output the gradients but isn't outputting the gradients in the `Distributions` tab?

All it is doing is just visualizing the weights and the biases

Comment: I think Tensorboard callback will not log weights. You need custom callback to do so